# Getting 403 Exception fetching web page programmatically even though web page is available via browser

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I'm trying to fetch the HTML of a page through code:

```
WebRequest r = WebRequest.Create(szPageURL);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
try
{
    WebResponse resp = r.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    szHTML = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This code works when I use URLs like www.microsoft.com, www.google.com, or www.nasa.gov.  However, when I put in www.epa.gov (using either 'http' or 'https' in the URL parameter), I get a 403 exception when executing     r.GetResponse().  Yet I can easily fetch the page manually in a browser.  The exception I'm getting is 403 (Forbidden) and the exception status member says "ProtocolError".  What does that mean?  Why I am I getting this on a page that actually is available?  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

BTW - I also tried this way:

```
string downloadString = client.DownloadString(szPageURL);
```

Got exact same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code, it works:

```
string Url = "https://www.epa.gov/";
CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
request.Accept = @"text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
request.Referer = @"https://www.epa.gov/";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-GB");
request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)";
request.Host = @"www.epa.gov";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
String htmlString;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
htmlString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So essentially my code didn't work because it was the equivalent of setting the browser to not accept cookies and then trying to access the page?